# Building the right search request with gem Tire and ElasticSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I am trying to implement simple search request for my Flower Store, but as I am new to Tire and ElasticSearch, I cannot get how to do it.

I have searchable model `Product`, and habtm models `Category`, `Colour`, `Flower`. What I want is checkboxes for each association, producing request similiar to this:

```
http://example.com/search?q=some%20query&category_names[]=bouquet&category_names[]=marriage&colour_names[]=red&colour_names[]=yellow&colour_names[]=white&flower_names[]=rose&flower_names[]=tulip&price_min=100&price_max=1000
```

But I need to show only those products, which:

```
a) prestent in any of the requested categories (OR);
b) have all of the requested colours (AND);
c) have all of the requested flowers (AND);
d) enter the price range between price_min and price_max.
```

The `q` parameter is to search any text, entered to the text field, in the names of associations (let's say, `red roses bouquet`), and show it with the upper criteria too.

For now I have only

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :colours
  has_and_belongs_to_many :flowers

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 8) do |search|
      search.query  { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    self.to_json(methods: [:category_names, :colour_names])
  end

  def category_names
    self.categories.collect { |c| c.name }
  end

  def colour_names
    self.colours.collect { |c| c.name }
  end
end
```

and do not know how to configure it. I read about `filters` and `facets`, but because English is not my native I cannot uderstand what is what and how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it so:

```
def self.search(params)
  tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 8) do
    query do
      boolean do
        must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
        must { string params[:category_names] } if params[:category_names].present?
        must { string params[:colour_names], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:colour_names].present?
        must { range :price, { gte: params[:price_min], lte: params[:price_max] } } if params[:price_min].present? && params[:price_max].present?
      end
    end

    # raise to_curl
  end
end
```